# Unable to Retry Immediately in GCP for pub/sub Service Accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam, spring-cloud-gcp

I am new to GCP pub/sub and am trying to get everything setup. I am facing a permission error when creating a subscription topic. Does anyone know what I am missing in my steps, or how to resolve? Here is what I have done so far.

1. Add roles, `Service Account Admin` and `Service Account Key Admin`
2. Created Service Account (completed the full flow)
3. Tried to create a subscription topic <-- this is where I am receiving an error.

[image]

Here is the error at a closer look.

[image]

UPDATE: After receiving some comments, it seems my issues are all related to roles and permissions. The problem is that I do not know which roles/permissions work.

I am able to create a subscription topic so long that I do NOT enable authentication and add a service account. Since my original post, I have added these other additional permissions: `Pub/Sub Admin`, `Service Account Admin`, `Service Account Key Admin`, `Service Account Token Creator`, `Service Account User`.

Comment: Are you sure that's the issue? If you set "retry after exponential backoff", does it work? I doubt...

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere What else would cause Permission denied error? I didn't think I would need any other permissions than what I have already added. Is it a bug, you think?

Comment: I don't think it is a bug but that your account doesn't have permissions to create the subscription. This is not related to the service account permissions

Comment: You are right. I am missing subscription permission. So many permissions required. Wow! Thank you.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder Is your issue resolved after adding the permissions?

Comment: @kiranmathew Thanks for asking. No, it's not resolved. I have learned that when you "Enable Authentication" you need more than "Pub/Sub Admin", "Service Account Admin", "Service Account Key Admin", and "Service Account Token Creator". I added "Service Account User" and just had to resort to assigning "Owner" in the end.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder Can you confirm whether you are still getting the “Permission denied ” message after giving the owner role?